# Count rows in relational database

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have a coupon code site. I'm creating a "Black Friday" coupons and deals page.

In the sidebar I want the user to be able to see all the categories of coupons we have (apparel,shoes,electronics,etc.) and how many Black Friday coupons we have for each category.

I'm pulling in all the categories from the table "tblCategories", but what I'm having issues with is getting a count from the relational table "tblCouponsCategories" of how many coupons are in the "Black Friday" category, plus whatever other category I'm looking for. The categoryid from Black Friday is '24'. This is the code I have so far:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name,fmtc_categoryid,categoryid FROM tblCategories ORDER BY name") or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
   $fmtc_categoryid=$row['fmtc_categoryid'];
   $categoryid=$row['categoryid'];
   $name=$row['name'];

   $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT couponid FROM tblCouponsCategories WHERE categoryid='24' AND categoryid='$categoryid'") or die(mysql_error()); 
   $count_coupons = mysql_num_rows($result2);

   echo "<li><a href='http://www.mydomain.com/coupons/$fmtc_categoryid' title='View $name Coupon Codes'>$name ($count_coupons)</a></li>";
}
```

Here is what my relational table tblCouponsCategories is formatted like for a coupon that is both in the "Black Friday" category plus another category:

```
id  couponid  categoryid    
83995   48312     5 
83996   48312     9 
83997   48312     14    
83998   48312     11    
83999   48312     24    
84000   48312     38
```

Answer (score 0):

I tink you have some mistake here:

```
SELECT couponid FROM tblCouponsCategories WHERE categoryid='24' AND categoryid='$categoryid' GROUP BY categoryid") or die(mysql_error()); 

//should be
SELECT couponid FROM tblCouponsCategories WHERE categoryid='24' GROUP BY categoryid") or die(mysql_error());
```